# Linq to entities: finding matches

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have these two EF classes:

```
 class Row
 {
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public long VesselId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vessel Vessel { get; set; }
    public int TruckType { get; set; }
 }

 class RowFilter
 {
    public long? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public long? VesselId { get; set; }
    public virtual Vessel Vessel { get; set; }
    public int? TruckType { get; set; }
    public long? PortId { get; set; }
    public virtual Port Port { get; set; }

    public bool IsMatch(Row row) 
    {
       if (CategoryId == null || CategoryId == row.CategoryId) {
         if (VesselId == null || VesselId == row.VesselId) {
           if (TruckType == null || TruckType == row.TruckType) {
             if (PortId == null || PortId == row.Vessel.PortId) {
                return true;
             }
           }
         }
       }

       return false;
    }
 }
```

That is:
A `Filter` matches a `Row` if `IsMatch()` returns true for that row.

I have a list of rows, in an `IQueryable` manner:

```
   var rows = dbContext.Rows.AsQueryable().Where(...);
```

...and for each row, I want to select (project) the row itself and the list of filters that match this row. I can do this easily in a Linq-to-Objects way ("in memory"):

```
   // Linq-to-objects

   rows.ToList().Select(r => new 
   {
       row = r,
       filters = dbContext.RowsFilters.Where(f => f.IsMatch(r))
   };
```

Question is... **is it possible to do it with Linq-to-Entities?** (sql, not "in memory")

In a static world, I would have these navigation properties:

```
 class Row
 {
    ...
    public virtual List<RowFilter> RowFilters { get; set; }
 }

 class RowFilter
 {
    ...
    public virtual List<Rows> Rows { get; set; }
 }
```

but... that means a lot of updating: when creating a new RowFilter, when creating a new Row, etc.

Comment: Is `Row.CategoryId` a field or a property? In your code it seems like a field.

Comment: a property, sorry... will edit

Comment: Some `RowFilter`  properties have no name. I think you missed them.

Comment: Can you also provide the missing types. Please make sure that the code you provide can compile and is correct.

Comment: So I deleted my answer because it not answer your issue.

Comment: too bad... maybe it can be mixed with Yacoub's answer, by creating the `Where` expression as a method: `public Expression<Func<Row, bool>> IsMatch() { Expression<Func<Row, bool>> filter = r => (.......); return filter; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
var query = from r in context.Rows
    from f in context.RowFilters.Where(f =>
        (f.CategoryId == null || f.CategoryId == r.CategoryId) &&
        (f.VesselId == null || f.VesselId == r.VesselId) &&
        (f.TruckType == null || f.TruckType == r.TruckType) &&
        (f.PortId == null || f.PortId == r.Vessel.PortId))
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    let x = new {r, f}
    group x by x.r
    into gr
    select new
    {
        row = gr.Key,
        filters = gr.Select(y => y.f).Where(yf => yf != null)
    };

var result = query.ToList();
```

Here is an alternative syntax:

```
var query = context.Rows
    .SelectMany(r =>
        context.RowFilters.Where(f =>
            (f.CategoryId == null || f.CategoryId == r.CategoryId) &&
            (f.VesselId == null || f.VesselId == r.VesselId) &&
            (f.TruckType == null || f.TruckType == r.TruckType) &&
            (f.PortId == null || f.PortId == r.Vessel.PortId))
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .Select(f => new {r, f}))
    .GroupBy(x => x.r)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        row = x.Key,
        filters = x.Select(y => y.f).Where(yf => yf != null)
    });
```

Comment: wow! looks promising... how would you write the first part: `from r in context.Rows from f in context.RowFilters` with lambda expressions?

Comment: wow, using `context` inside a `SelectMany` seems to be the trick :p awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following steps:

Modify the `IsMatch` method to return a `Expression<Func<Row, bool>>` type and implement it like this :

```
public Expression<Func<Row, bool>> IsMatch()
{
    Expression<Func<Row, bool>> filter = r => (CategoryId == null || CategoryId == r.CategoryId)
                    && (VesselId == null || VesselId == r.VesselId)
                    && (TruckType == null || TruckType == r.TruckType)
                    && (PortId == null || PortId == r.PortId);

    return filter;
}
```

Then just use it like this :

```
var rowFilter = new RowFilter { PortId = 1, CategoryId = 2, TruckType = 3, VesselId = 4 };
var query = context.Rows.Where(rowFilter.IsMatch());
```

All the linq are translated into SQL then executed on the server side. The generated SQL by EF looks like the following:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId], 
    [Extent1].[VesselId] AS [VesselId], 
    [Extent1].[TruckType] AS [TruckType], 
    [Extent1].[PortId] AS [PortId]
FROM [dbo].[Rows] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (@p__linq__0 IS NULL OR @p__linq__1 = [Extent1].[CategoryId]) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL OR @p__linq__3 = [Extent1].[VesselId]) AND (@p__linq__4 IS NULL OR @p__linq__5 = [Extent1].[TruckType]) AND (@p__linq__6 IS NULL OR @p__linq__7 =  CAST( [Extent1].[PortId] AS bigint))
```

Comment: With your query: `var query = context.Rows.Where(rowFilter.IsMatch());` you are returning all the Rows that match a single RowFilter. What I want is  a bit different, I quote myself: "`I want to select (project) the row itself and the list of filters that match this row`". That is: an array with this shape: `[{someRow, filters}, {otherRow, filters}, ...]`

Comment: No. I'm not returning all rows.  rowFilter` is an instance of `RowFilter`. The returned rows match the values you setted to the properties of `rowFilter`instance.

Comment: Check the generated SQL in my answer you can see that there is a where clause.

Comment: I don't have a `RowFilter` instance a priori...  `RowsFilters` are stored in a database table